# PHP echoing '<<<'

Tags: php, browser, echo, html-entities

I want to echo some HTML from PHP that contains a link that has the text '<<< Back' on it. I can't get the '<<<' to display properly.

Anybody have any ideas? This is my current code:

```
  $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp; <span class="paginationNumbersbn"> <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> '<<<'Back</a></span> ';
```

Comment: `<` is a reserved character in HTML, so the browser sees it and thinks you're starting an HTML tag. You need to html-encode any html reserved characters that you want to display in an html page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to display a literal less-than sign, encode it as `&lt;` as per the HTML spec.

You might also want to look into another related entity: `&laquo;`. This produces a double left angle quote:

```
«
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape it, as it has nothing to do with PHP.

Often websites just print out <, instead of using the appropriate HTML entity.

Try the following:

```
  $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp; <span class="paginationNumbersbn"> <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '"> &lt;&lt;&lt;Back</a></span> ';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp; <span class="paginationNumbersbn"> <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $previous . '">&lt;&lt;&lt;Back</a></span>';
```

`&lt;` = <
`&gt;` = >

You can use these and many other HTML entities to put symbols like this into your page.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't work properly because PHP attaches a special meaning to <<< called HEREDOC. You are better off encoding each < as `&lt;` and then displaying it as the others suggested.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: heredoc is not relevant here because the `<<<` is inside a string. It's just a string that happens to contain three `<` characters. Yes, it needs to be html encoded, but that's because he's trying to display it in an HTML page, where `<` is a reserved character; it has nothing to do with heredoc.